# Связанные таблицы

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите, как в laravel вывести связанные таблицы? Т.е. у меня есть таблица с расписанием и таблица с преподавателями, на одном расписании может быть несколько преподавателей. И мне нужно, чтобы при выборе таба и нажатии на кнопку показать тренеров, отображались соответствующие преподы.

```html
<section class="made_life_area p_120">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="made_life_inner">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        @foreach($time as $el)
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link {{ $el->active }}" id="home-{{ $el->id }}" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab{{ $el->id }}" role="tab" aria-controls="tab{{ $el->id }}" aria-selected="true">{{ $el->city }}</a>
          </li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">

        @foreach($time as $el)
        <div class="tab-pane fade show {{ $el->active }}" id="tab{{ $el->id }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-{{ $el->id }}">
          <div class="row made_life_text">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h3 class="text-center">{{ $el->title }}</h3>
              <img src="/assets/img/timetable/{{ $el->img }}" class="single-gallery-image-time">
            </div>

            @foreach($teacher as $el)
            <div class="content_block col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12 mt-3">
              <img src="/assets/img/people/{{ $el->img }}" class="single-gallery-image-time-two">
            </div>
            <div class="content_block col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-12 mt-3">
              <h3 class="text-center">{{ $el->lesson }}</h3>
              {!! $el->text !!}
            </div>
            @endforeach

          </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a class="content_toggle btn main_btn mt-5" onClick="teacher()" href="#">Показать тренеров</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

```php
$time = DB::table('timetable')->get();
$teacher = DB::table('teacher')->get();
view()->share(['inform' => $inform, 'time' => $time, 'teacher' => $teacher]);
```

Comment: А что у вас не работает?

Comment: @ArchDemon ну так выводятся то все преподаватели у всех расписаний. А мне нужно, чтобы при выборе конкретного таба, выводились и конкретные преподы. Я и спрашиваю, как это делается?

Comment: А как преподы связаны с конкретным табом?

Comment: @ArchDemon в БД у расписания есть колонка с id преподавателей  {"id":[1,2]}

Comment: Добавьте в цикл по учителям условие "если id преподавателя из id преподавателей расписания, то отобразить преподавателя"